# Convert DatetimeWithNanoseconds to date format in python firestore

Tags: python, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to convert a firestore timestamp into milliseconds or a date format using python to perform a calculation using this date. Trying to parse it to date returns.

> `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not DatetimeWithNanoseconds.`

How can I convert a Firestore timestamp into milliseconds/date format in python?  I need this to perform a calculation.

```
docs = db.collection(u'status').stream()

for doc in docs:
    doc_data = doc.to_dict()

    # TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not DatetimeWithNanoseconds
    utc_time = datetime.strptime(doc_data['start_date'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Comment: I have managed to get something going by converting the doc_data['start_date'] to string using:
str(doc_data['start_date'])

My problem now is the formatting, some dates are formatted with milliseconds while others are not
Example 1: 2019-12-08 17:00:00+00:00 
Example 2: 2019-12-29 01:37:29.982000+00:00
I believe the first date with created using the firebase GUI while the second date was created programmatically with firestore.timestamp

Answer (score 18):

[It turns out that `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` inherits from `datetime.datetime` already](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/helpers.html)

Answer (score 17):

**Converting `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` to `datetime.datetime`:**

```py
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(datetime_with_nanoseconds.timestamp())
```

*Leaving this answer here despite not addressing converting to date format directly, as this is the only post regarding this conversion and I haven't seen this simple direct solution published anywhere.*

Answer (score 7):

As implied by Luke's answer, you can use all of the usual methods of `datetime` with values of `DatetimeWithNanoseconds`, because it's a subclass. So for example you can do `doc_data['start_date'].timestamp()` to get the time in seconds since 1970-01-01 (including fractional seconds).

However, from experimenting and looking at the [implementation of DatetimeWithNanoseconds](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/_modules/google/api_core/datetime_helpers.html#DatetimeWithNanoseconds), I've noticed some issues that developers should be aware of (and possibly that Google should fix).

`DatetimeWithNanoseconds` adds a read-only `nanosecond` property to `datetime`, but keeps its `microsecond` property. The intent appears to be that you can set one or the other, but not both, when creating the object, and then read either one. When using the `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` constructor, you can either set `microsecond` or `nanosecond`, but not both (if setting `nanosecond`, it must be specified as a keyword argument). If you try to set both, it throws an exception. If you only set `nanosecond`, it correctly sets `microsecond` to `nanosecond / 1000`, rounded down. If you only set `microsecond`, it sets `microsecond`, but `nanosecond` is set to zero.

```
>>> from google.api_core.datetime_helpers import DatetimeWithNanoseconds
>>> d1 = DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2020, 6, 22, 17, 1, 30, 12345)
>>> d1.microsecond
12345
>>> d1.nanosecond
0
>>> d2 = DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2020, 6, 22, 17, 1, 30, nanosecond=1234567)
>>> d2.microsecond
1234
>>> d2.nanosecond
1234567
```

If you construct a `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` in other ways, like for example `DatetimeWithNanoseconds.now()`, you always get a value with `nanosecond` set to zero.

```
>>> now = DatetimeWithNanoseconds.now()
>>> now.microsecond
51570
>>> now.nanosecond
0
```

The values that I get when fetching documents from Firestore always seem to have `nanosecond` set to zero! So if I were to fetch a document with a timestamp, then write it back to Firestore, it would lose precision. (Though admittedly I am using a pretty old version of `firebase-admin`, so it may have been fixed in a more recent version.)

I'm currently doing something like this to extract the seconds and nanoseconds from a timestamp (I use this in a context where I'm not sure if the timestamp is a `datetime` or a `DatetimeWithNanoseconds`):

```
def get_seconds_and_nanoseconds(val):
    if isinstance(val, datetime_helpers.DatetimeWithNanoseconds) and val.nanosecond:
        return {
            'nanoseconds': val.nanosecond,
            'seconds': int(val.timestamp()),
        }
    if isinstance(val, datetime):
        return {
            'nanoseconds': 1000 * int(val.microsecond),
            'seconds': int(val.timestamp()),
        }
    raise TypeError(f'Not a datetime or DatetimeWithNanoseconds')
```

And to construct a correct `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` from seconds and nanoseconds, I do this:

```
def datetime_with_nanoseconds(seconds, nanoseconds):
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds, tz=timezone.utc)
    dtnanos = datetime_helpers.DatetimeWithNanoseconds(
        dt.year,
        dt.month,
        dt.day,
        dt.hour,
        dt.minute,
        dt.second,
        nanosecond=nanoseconds,
        tzinfo=dt.tzinfo,
    )
    return dtnanos
```

It's ugly, but I haven't found a more concise way yet.

Answer (score 4):

The `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` is an object so you have to use its attributes. To view its attributes use `print(dir(doc_data['start_date']))`.Finally you can format it to a string the below code shows how.

```
docs = db.collection(u'status').stream()

for doc in docs:
    doc_data = doc_data.to_dict()
    val1 = doc_data['start_date']
    year,month,day,hour,minute,second,tzinfo = val1.year,val1.month,val1.day,val1.hour, val1.minute, val1.second, val1.tzinfo
    utc_time  = "%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s.%s"%(year, month, day,hour,minute,second,tzinfo)
```

Comment: I believe there's and extra '%' in your format string.

Comment: just changed it 

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
try:
    utc_time = strptime(''.join(str(doc_data['start_date']).rsplit(':', 1)), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
except Exception as e:
    if type(e) is ValueError:
        utc_time = strptime(''.join(str(doc_data['start_date']).rsplit(':', 1)), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
    else :
        print(e)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime 

# here a is instance of 'google.api_core.datetime_helpers.DatetimeWithNanoseconds'

# we use datetime.combine method to convert DatetimeWithNanosecond into datetime object

answer = datetime.datetime.combine(date=a.date(), time=a.time(), tzinfo=a.tzinfo)

print(type(answer)

# it will be class datetime
```

visit https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine