# how to replace datetime fields in Python DatetimeWithNanoseconds object

Tags: python, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, python-datetime

In Python, I need to set a timestamp field in a google-cloud firestore document.

I know that the `firestore` timestamp field shall be set using `google.api_core.datetime_helpers.DatetimeWithNanoseconds`, which is a subclass of `Datetime`

I need to set the now() timestamp with a specified minute field and dial it back by certain hours as given below

```
                'cursor_specs' = {
                    # specs to construct the next cursor
                    'minute_tick': 0,
                    'hours_dial_back': 1,
                },
```

Because `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` is a subclass of `Datetime` and supposedly inherits all its function, so I tried to use now() and replace() directly with `DatetimeWithNanoseconds`

```
from google.api_core.datetime_helpers import DatetimeWithNanoseconds

time_cursor = DatetimeWithNanoseconds.now().replace(minute=cursor_specs['minute_tick'],
                                    second=0, microsecond=0
                                ) - timedelta(hours=cursor_specs['hours_dial_back']

fs_model = fs.document(model["name"]).set({'time_cursor': time_cursor})
```

It failed with an error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 219, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: encode_value(value) for key, value in values_dict.items()}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 173, in encode_value
    return document.Value(timestamp_value=value.timestamp_pb())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/datetime_helpers.py", line 271, in timestamp_pb
    nanos = self._nanosecond or self.microsecond * 1000
AttributeError: _nanosecond
```

Comment: related: [Convert DatetimeWithNanoseconds to date format in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59516984/10197418)

Answer (score 2):

I posted this question because I struggled with it so I hope my finding could help others.

The best solution I found is to use now() and replace() to set a regular `Datetime` object first, and then convert it to a `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` object.

```
from google.api_core.datetime_helpers import DatetimeWithNanoseconds
from google.api_core.datetime_helpers import to_rfc3339

time_cursor_in_datetime = datetime.now().replace(
                                minute=model['cursor']['next']['minute_tick'],
                                second=0, microsecond=0
                            ) - timedelta(hours=model['cursor']['next']['hours_dial_back'])

time_cursor =  DatetimeWithNanoseconds.from_rfc3339(
                                to_rfc3339(time_cursor_in_datetime)
                            )


fs_model = fs.document(model["name"]).set({'time_cursor': time_cursor})
```

Comment: The conversion to and from RFC3339 (string I assume) seems like a detour. Didn't they add a direct conversion method?

Comment: yes, it really is a detour. That's the best I found last time I looked it up. Would really love to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is using the `default=str` option in the `json.dumps()` function:

```py
import json

# Firestore API code to get data 
...

firestoreResult = docRef.get().to_dict()  # DatetimeWithNanoseconds format 

outputWithTimestamp = json.dumps(, indent=4, default=str)
```

All `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` will now show up in the format
`"my_timestamp": "2022-02-26 09:07:47.223000+00:00"`.

Google Firestore example of `to_dict()`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document